# Select para contar quantidade por coluna

Tags: sql, sql-select

Como eu faço um select que retorne a quantidade dos equipamentos que repetem, e a primeira e a última data destes registros?

```
Equipamento  |     Data     | Causa  |

   B            01/01/2017      x
   B            03/04/2017      Y
   A            05/01/2017      Y
   A            25/01/2017      x
   A            25/06/2017      Y
   C            01/05/2017      x
   C            01/06/2017      Y
   C            15/07/2017      x
   R            01/01/2017      x
   K            01/01/2017      x
```

..neste exemplo eu precisaria que retornasse conforme abaixo:

```
Equipamento  |    Quantidade  |   Data1      |  DAta2   

   B                  2          01/01/2017    03/04/2017   
   A                  3          05/01/2017    25/06/2017
   C                  3          01/05/2017    15/07/2017
```

estou utilizando o Access

Comment: select count(*), equipamento, max(data) as data1 , min(data) as data2 from tabela group by equipamento

Comment: O amigo acima está correto. Um exemplo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d61ef/4

Comment: @DiegoSchmidt K e R não são equipamento que se repetem ... faltou o Having  count(*) > 1

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza Boa, realmente não prestei atenção nesse detalhe da pergunta, segue: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d61ef/15

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo auxílio!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisar Usar o Max e Min para pegar as datas da máximas e minima agrupa o Equipamento e usar o having para verificar quais estão com quantidade maior que 1 que serão os repetidos.

```
select Equipamento, count(*) as Quantidade, max(data) as Data1 , min(data) as Data2 
from SuaTabela_Equipamento 
group by Equipamento
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: O `having` não vai reconhecer o alias `Quantidade`. Vai dá erro. É necessário substituir `having Quantidade` por `having count(*)`

Comment: E tem como eu não incluir no COUNT(*) se a data for repetida para o mesmo equipamento?